# Tomcat responds with a file containing hostname

Tags: tomcat

I'm brushing up on my tomcat after over a decade. I downloaded and installed Tomcat 7, configured it to run on port 9999.

From Chrome, if I hit a URL on that server, Chrome simply downloads a file which contains just the hostname in it, rather than actually loading a page.

I'm missing something very basic. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the behavior of Chrome. It has nothing to do with Tomcat at all. You could stop Tomcat and it would still happen. You probably need to specify http://. Some browsers assume it for you, some don't.